# Tengo que saber el numero de caracteres coincidentes con un argumento

Tags: javascript

```
function mismaCantidadCaracteres(strings, caracteres) {

  // La función llamada 'mismaCantidadCaracteres', recibe como argumento un arreglo de strings llamado 'strings'
  
// y un numero entero llamado 'caracteres'
  // Debe devolver en un array los strings que tengan el numero de caracteres coincidentes con 'caracteres'
  
// Ej:
  
// mismaCantidadCaracteres(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag'], 2) debe retornar ['hi'] ya que 'hi' tiene 2 caracteres
  
// mismaCantidadCaracteres(['javascript', 'pedro', 'amigo', 'parque'], 5) debe retornar ['pedro', 'amigo']

  
// Tu código aca:
}
```

Esto es lo que intenté

```
var obj = {};
for (let i=0; i < string.length; i++){
  if(!obj[string[i]]) {
    obj[string[i]] = 0;
  }
  obj[string[i]] += 1;
}
return obj;
}
```

Comment: Entonces...que es lo que has [intentado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884)? Solo pones el enunciado de tu ejercicio sin mas como "pidiendo que te lo resolvamos", y eso no es bien recibido en el sitio

Comment: por favor revisa [ask], como ya lo mencionaron en un comentario, este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas en el sitio.

Comment: ya que agregaste lo que intentaste, te regresa algún error? o que problema presentas ?

Comment: Si me tira error al pasar el test @Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar todos los elementos del array con un criterio específico, en este caso, la propiedad `length` del string tiene que ser igual al segundo parámetro

```js
function mismaCantidadCaracteres(s, c) {
  // Como validación extra
  // if (!Array.isArray(s)) return;
  // Para asegurar que "s" sea un array
  return s.filter(e => e.length === c);
  // También: s.filter(e => typeof e === "string" && e.length === c);
  // Para asegurarnos de solo filtrar elementos que sean strings
}

console.log(mismaCantidadCaracteres(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag'], 2)); // ["hi"]
console.log(mismaCantidadCaracteres(['javascript', 'pedro', 'amigo', 'parque'], 5)); // ["pedro", "amigo"]
```

Comment: Me funciono. Muchas gracias @anythingg

Comment: @Aeg97 Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si soluciono tu problema, marcando en la palomita.